# SQL keep data after update

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I can't figure a way to structure this database effectively. I have the following structure, however, I need to keep track of previous locations if it's updated and allow editing/updating of the first name and last name.

User

- ID (Auto-Increment, primary)
- Username (Unique)
- FirstName
- LastName
- Location

The part which I don't get is how to essentially archive the user's previous location.

Comment: you can append the location with ',newloc" and in actual code use the last one only via exploding it into an array

Comment: You can create a second table of locations with ID, Location and any other data you want to save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create table `PREVIOUS_LOCATION - ID, USER_ID, LOCATION, TIMESTAMP`, put an `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger on table `USER`, that will insert `USER_ID`, current `LOCATION` and time of insert and you have complete history of all users locations

Comment: Thanks for your response.
Am I correct in thinking that the ID being the primary key, user_id being the foreign key?

Answer (score 0):

There are various possibilities to this.

One is as follows:

1. Save the location as a csv, appending it each time with the newer one like this: "`,newone`" this way you will always have all the previous entries.
2. retrieve the location list and `explode` it into an array, and use the last item.

You can enhance it by having two fields for location, one having only the current one while the other having appended csv one.